# Name for minimum size of a set of vertices S such that every other vertex has a neighbor in S

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given a (non-multi)graph $G$ let $N_G$ be the least number of nodes that must be colored (by a single color) such that every other node in $G$ shares an edge with at least one colored node. (I am only interested in the case where $G$ is an $n \times n$ grid, where such an $N_G$ obviously always make sense - I don't know what constraints (or their names) must be put on $G$ in general for $N_G$ to make sense, but assume 'obvious' ones.)

Is there a technical, graph-theoretic term for $N_G$?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't tag the question "graph-colorings." 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the domination number of the graph.

Here's a wikipedia article:

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set)

Comment: To stress the point further, this is not a coloring concept at all.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: good point, though perhaps he just found this to be a convenient language in which to explain his question.